# Как попасть в панель управления MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Как попасть в панель управления MySQL?

Comment: У вас хостинг или локальный сервер?

Comment: Локальный, наверно, я не знаю.

Comment: @Инкогнито чито? Как это вы не знаете? Вкратце – локальный сервер это ваш компьютер, удаленный сервер это удаленный сервер (или хостинг), если вы и так не поймете – вы точно разработчик?

Answer (score 1):

В вопросе слишком мало информации, чтобы дать исчерпывающий ответ. Предполагаю, что у вас установлен phpMyAdmin и в в него-то вы и хотите попасть. Обычно на хостингах в панели управления есть на него ссылка (типа "Базы MySQL" и т.п.). Либо по адресам `localhost/phpmyadmin`, или `domain/phpmyadmin`, или подобным в зависимости от настроек веб-сервера.